# Issues in store-fed dijit/form/Select by setting preselected value in dojo 1.8

Tags: select, dojo

There is another issue when I try to set the preselected (or any) value of my store-fed dijit/form/Select widget.

The markup code is:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" jsId="editOptionsDialog_select" id="editOptionsDialog_select"></div>
```

and the js:

```
function editOptionsDialog_fetchData(cId, fieldName, vId) {
        var store;
        var def;
        var return_def = new Deferred();

        store = new degreeStore();
        def = store.getJsonData();

        def.then(function(data) {
            store.data = data.items;
            editOptionsDialog_select.setStore(new ObjectStore({
                objectStore : store
            }));

            editOptionsDialog_select.value = vId;

            editOptionsDialog_select.startup();
            editOptionsDialog_select.set('value', 5);

            console.info(editOptionsDialog_select);
            // here, firebug still shows value = 1
            return_def.resolve();
        });

        return return_def;
    }
```

thx in advance

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found a solution to the problem:**

Since the selection-element DOES NOT support numerical indexes, the indexes had to be casted to strings. With that, a editOptionsDialog_select.set('value', vId.toString()) has finally worked!

Be sure to feed your store by casted numerical ids or then textual-keys by default -> (String)id where id is an integer.

Greetings